# Raspberry pi 3 bridge Wifi to Lan

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, raspberry-pi, bridge

I have a RPi-3 which can act as AP but with its own IP address range tried to follow this guide https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/ but it just cut off my network

really, what I want is for my pi's connected WIFI devices to be part of my main network, cause I need them visible from the lan

this should be simple, but somehow .. I miss something

Comment: How is the Pi connect to the existing network, via Ethernet or Wi-Fi?

Comment: the pi is connected via Ethernet, I want wifi devices to be included in the same network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a rather old tutorial that will not work properly on Raspbian Stretch.

On Raspbian Stretch you better set your static IPs in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

I suggest you to try the [current tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) of the Raspberry Pi foundation.

Comment: tried that too,  when I run 
        `sudo ifup br0 `
I get 

    `can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported`

Comment: also, I don't get this: I have eth0, wlan0 AND br0
does each get its own IP address ? I would like to give the eth0 a static IP and if needed the wlan0 a static IP too (though I am not sure why I need both a wlan0 AND a bridge IP)

--- edit -- 
also - it's never mentioned anywhere, but do I need to turn wlan on using `raspi-config` ?

Comment: As the tutorial is verified to work with a brand new installation of Raspbian Stretch, I can only assume that you have "broken" something with your previous attempts. One suspect being the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Did you remove all the stuff you put in there from the tutorial you linked?
And yes the wlan0 interface needs to be up. Check e.g. via `ifconfig`.

Comment: I think what broke it that I didn't see the wlan active and I tried to activiate it through `raspi-config` which actually broke the process, it's working now, thanks !